# WP migration from apache to nginx results -- 404 -- on https

Tags: wordpress, nginx, https, http-status-code-404, nginx-config

That was kind of a loaded title. 
I moved my site over from Apache to Nginx and I'm learning the hard way that Nginx does things its own ways. It does not like htaccess files, ignores them. This causes problems when running Wordpress, because wordpress supposedly loves to use htaccess files and nginx does not. Why? I have no idea.

Anyways,

I managed to figure out how to bring back the site from the abyss of 404, by placing this code in nginx.conf file

```
location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
        }
}
```

But.

while pages load fine on HTTP, HTTPS still shows dreaded 404. Why? I don't know. So, anybody know what to do next?

Comment: try :  
`location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I also have to add the same code on nginx.ssl.conf file.
Why? I don't know, but it works.